# How to publish a custom gradle plugin with maven-publish using custom publication schemes?

Tags: maven, gradle, gradle-plugin

I've built a custom gradle plugin that I'm trying to publish to a private maven repo. I use the `MavenPublication` plugin to accomplish this. After much trouble I looked at the implementation of the google play services plugin (https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/blob/master/google-services-plugin/publish.gradle)  and tried to copy from that.

It turns out that publishing works correctly ONLY when I add a single publication named `pluginMaven`, so my configuration must look as follows:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

publishing {
    publications {
        pluginMaven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.magicbluepenguin'
            artifactId = 'mbpplugin'
            version = '1.0.0'
            artifact sourcesJar
        }
    }
}
```

Which adds the 2 tasks below to my project:

[image]

This works and I am able to push my plugin to my remote repo and then pull it and apply to my sample client app. The problems start if I want to use a different publication name - or several. In that case, the new tasks built on my publications will be added *alongside* the "default" ones. So for example, if I have the following publication block:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

publishing {
    publications {
        pluginMavenDevelop(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.magicbluepenguin'
            artifactId = 'mbpplugin'
            version = '1.0.0'
            artifact sourcesJar
        }
    }
}
```

The following 4 tasks are added to my project:

[image]

And of course there are problems with this:

- Calling the "default" task now fails because it's `artifactId,`version` etc. have not been defined.
- Calling the custom task succeeds, but trying to use the plugin from a client app fails with a `Plugin with id 'mbpplugin' not found` error.

Somehow I now need to be able to define custom publications for develop, staging and production but I really have no idea how to deal with this issue and haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Are the plugins completely different plugins or the same plugin? You publication block uses the same plugin GAV for both examples.

Comment: Same plugin for now. The idea is that I'll publish increasing versions to develop and then run the release task only when the project reaches an acceptable level of features and stability.

Comment: I see you found your solution, but I'd suggest having a single plugin and suppress/disable unready features via a feature flag of some sort. This is how Gradle does it via [`enableFeaturePreview("...")`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#enableFeaturePreview-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround by using appropriate arguments. My task now looks as follows:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

publishing {
    publications {
        pluginMaven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.magicbluepenguin'
            artifactId = 'mbpplugin'
            if (project.hasProperty('versionArgs')) {
                version = version + project.findProperty('versionArgs')
            }
            artifact sourcesJar
        }
    }
}
```

With this I can now keep publishing my plugin as a development version by calling the following:

`./gradlew buildSrc:publishPluginMavenPublicationToMavenRepository -PversionArgs=-develop`

And then publish the release version by calling the task without the version argument. Certainly this isn't the most flexible and ideal solution but for now it allows me to keep moving forward.